# transform query in mysql or Mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to transform the following query from SQL Server 2012 to MySQL, I don't have experience in SQL Server transcript so I've found difficult to figure out.

Table details,

```
create table T
(
 Id int primary key,
 ParentId int,
 Name varchar(10),
 ProductCount int
);

insert into T values
(1, -1, 'Cars',    0),
(2, -1, 'Bikes',   1),
(3,  1, 'Ford',    10),
(4,  3, 'Mustang', 7),
(5,  3, 'Focus',   4);

   create index IX_T_ParentID on T(ParentID) include(ProductCount, Id);
```

Sql Server query,

```
with C as
(
select T.Id,
     T.ProductCount,
     T.Id as RootID
 from T
 union all
 select T.Id,
     T.ProductCount,
     C.RootID
 from T
 inner join C 
  on T.ParentId = C.Id

 )
select T.Id,
   T.ParentId,
   T.Name,
   T.ProductCount,
   S.ProductCountIncludingChildren
from T
inner join (
         select RootID,
                sum(ProductCount) as ProductCountIncludingChildren
         from C
         group by RootID
         ) as S
 on T.Id = S.RootID
 order by T.Id
 option (maxrecursion 0);
```

I've never used include, option , with x as in SQL

Comment: Looks like a recursive cte. Probably all you need to do is remove the max recursion hint

Comment: Why does the title say Mariadb, but the content says SQL Server..?

Answer (score 2):

This query is portable except query hint `option (maxrecursion 0);`:

```
with C as
(
select T.Id,
     T.ProductCount,
     T.Id as RootID
 from T
 union all
 select T.Id,
     T.ProductCount,
     C.RootID
 from T
 inner join C 
  on T.ParentId = C.Id

 )
select T.Id,
   T.ParentId,
   T.Name,
   T.ProductCount,
   S.ProductCountIncludingChildren
from T
inner join (
         select RootID,
                sum(ProductCount) as ProductCountIncludingChildren
         from C
         group by RootID
         ) as S
 on T.Id = S.RootID
 order by T.Id
```

Starting from MySQL 8.0 common table expressions are supported.

Comment: @RodrigoCabrera Which version of MySQL/MariaDB are you using?